# Control principal eigenvector of a row stochastic matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, spectral-graph-theory

I am just trying to consider the classical discrete-time Markov Chain problem. Consider the transition matrix ***P***, which transforms state vector $x(k)$ to $x(k+1)$, satisfying:

$x(k+1)$ = $P*x(k)$

It is well known that the principal eigenvalue of ***P*** is $1$ and its corresponding right eigenvector is all 1 while its left eigenvector determines the expectation arrival rate of every state.

My question is that whether I can adjust the direction of the associated principal left eigenvector so I can control the final allocation ratio of every state.

The kind of adjustification can be made by re-allocating weights of elements in every row of ***P***. I am trying to find out the limit where I can control the direction of the expected eigenvector. And if possible, I want to find a definite way to drive the eigenvector to the designated direction.

Any suggestion is warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If your desired left eigenvector is a row vector $x$ with $x_i\ge0$ and $\sum x_i =1$, then the matrix
$$
P= \begin{pmatrix} x \\ x\\ \vdots \\ x\end{pmatrix}
$$
has $x$ as left eigenvector to the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Well, I know this conclusion. And my point is whether I can re-assign elements in this vector by adjusting elements in matrix P. Of course, during the operation, I will always keep P as a row stochastic matrix.